# Module with a list that match an argument

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Based on a gem I tried to create a module to my rails app with a list of keys - values:

```
module CodeMeaning
  def name_of_code
    CODES { "100" : "Continue",
      "101" : "Switching Protocols",
      "102" : "Processing",
      "200" : "OK",
      "201" : "Created
    }
  end
end
```

What is the best way to complete this module and being able to get the value of the argument, for example:

CodeMeaning.get_code(101.to_s) - respond "Switching Protocols"

I created something like this but it is not working and I am not sure what is the best practising & structure of a module like that:

```
  def self.name_of_code code
    CODE[code]
  end
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
module CodeMeaning
  CODES = {
            100 => "Continue",
            101 => "Switching Protocols",
            102 => "Processing",
            200 => "OK",
            201 => "Created"
          }.freeze 

  def name_of_code code
    CODES[code]
  end

  module_function :name_of_code
end

CodeMeaning.name_of_code(100) #=> "Continue"
```

I think this could work, if you are trying to call the method directly on the module

Edit: after comment in question.

> why did you use .freeze and

Sure. I used `.freeze` because it is good etiquette to make your constants immutable (however, note that the objects themselves are mutable if the are strings (integers are not), so be careful).

> what "module_function :name_of_code" means?

In most cases, modules are either included in or extended to a class.  So you generally do not have direct access to methods in module, except through the classes they are included in or extended to.  However, because ruby was written for developers, to be nice, and to give you the flexibility to do do something if it makes sense in your code, to call methods directly on modules by declaring that you intend to call it directly on the module using `module_function`.

Comment: Awesome, thanks Sean! Can you please let me know why did you use .freeze and what "module_function :name_of_code" means? Thank you.

Comment: @Dudis I edited my answer to include answers to your questions in the comments. Cheers